# How can I temporarily change scalaVersion in all sub-projects of my sbt build?

Tags: sbt

I like to sometimes try out a different version of scala by using `sbt`'s `set` command like so:

```
set scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

However this does not work as expected in a build with sub-projects

If I run `set scalaVersion := "2.11.6"` in the top-level project and then run `show scalaVersion`, I get the following:

```
> show scalaVersion
[info] sub1/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.5
[info] sub2/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.10.5
[info] master/*:scalaVersion
[info]  2.11.6
```

If I run `test` now, nothing really changed because the `master` project does not actually contain any code, so I am still testing Scala 2.10.5.

Is there an `sbt` command I am unaware of that would allow me to temporarily change the `scalaVersion` for all sub-projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `set every scalaVersion := "2.11.6"`.